Bernstein type representation with logarithmic kernel
Consider the integral operator $T$ which maps nonnegative measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^2$ such that $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left|\ln(ux+vy)\right|\,d\mu(u,v)<+\infty$$ into functions on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^2$ by the formula
$$T\mu(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\ln(ux+vy) \, d\mu(u,v).$$
How can the range of $T$ (that is, the set of functions $f$ such that $f =T\mu$ for some nonnegative $\mu$) be described more explicitly?
